# "byte indices must be integers or slices, not str" error in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, runtime-error

i'm trying to run anaconda navigator on windows 10. when i click the anaconda prompt it shows me some errors, when i try to run anaconda navigator it shows me another error and won't be run. so i uninstall it 3 times and also python but errors are still remains. i'm freaking out. 
**in second and third try to install anaconda, Add to Path section installation didn't show for me at all.**
my python is 3.6
can you help me out ?

> Navigator Error An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up
>
> Report Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker
>
> Main Error byte indices must be integers or slices, not str Traceback
>    TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

***i already searched stackoverflow and i couldn't find proper solution***
my anaconda prompt errors :

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 110, in main
        from ..activate import main as activator_main
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\activate.py", line 12, in <module>
        context.__init__()  # oOn import, context does not include SEARCH_PATH. This line fixes that.
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 234, in __init__
        argparse_args=argparse_args)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 723, in __init__
        self._set_search_path(search_path)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 729, in _set_search_path
        self._set_raw_data(load_file_configs(search_path))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 371, in load_file_configs
        raw_data = odict(kv for kv in chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 371, in <genexpr>
        raw_data = odict(kv for kv in chain.from_iterable(load_paths))
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 346, in _file_yaml_loader
        yield fullpath, YamlRawParameter.make_raw_parameters_from_file(fullpath)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\configuration.py", line 334, in make_raw_parameters_from_file
        ruamel_yaml = yaml_load(fh)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\common\serialize.py", line 54, in yaml_load
        return yaml.load(string, Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader, version="1.2")
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\main.py", line 637, in load
        loader = Loader(stream, version, preserve_quotes=preserve_quotes)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\loader.py", line 59, in __init__
        Reader.__init__(self, stream, loader=self)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 80, in __init__
        self.stream = stream  # type: Any  # as .read is called
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 125, in stream
        self.determine_encoding()
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 180, in determine_encoding
        self.update(1)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 241, in update
        self.check_printable(data)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ruamel_yaml\reader.py", line 208, in check_printable
        'unicode', "special characters are not allowed")
    ruamel_yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed
      in "C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc", position 0

`$ C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda shell.cmd.exe activate activate C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\Mohammad
                     PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Wind
                          ows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\W
                          indowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program
                          Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
                          Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
                          Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
                          SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
                          Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\T
                          ools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\P
                          ython\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Programs\Py
                          thon\Python36-32\;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS
                          Code\bin;C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\

     active environment : None
       user config file : C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.4.10
    conda-build version : 3.4.1
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Mohammad\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.10 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.10586
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]:
```

Comment: Please don't post code/terminal output in images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Comment: @darthbith, i correct it, can you help it ?

Comment: You still have all of the output in the images... you need to copy from the terminal and paste into this post

Comment: @darthbith all right then

Comment: @darthbith can you help me out now ?

Comment: Delete the file `C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc` and try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant error message is located here

```
ruamel_yaml.reader.ReaderError: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed
in "C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc", position 0
```

Deleting that file `C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc` should fix the problem.